# C# custom service does not start on 2008 Server

Tags: c#, debugging, service, windows-server-2008

I've build a little service (c# ,net 4). After a few tests and tuning on dev environment i've tried it on my own pc. All is working fine.

When I install the service on a windows 2008 R2 server (production environment) it won't start giving me a 1053 error (Service does not start in a timely fashion time)

tTe weird is that I get this error suddenly, as I start the service, just after a second or two.
I've added the option this.RequireMoreTime(120000) to my service, and I've edited the registry key of ServicePipelineMode.

Some more info:

- I'm using Log4net to log events in the Application log.
- I use a custom source (created using a powershell command)
- The service is set to run under Network Service Account, Starting it with an administrative account get same results
- I've put every part under Try - catch using log.error(exception.tostring()) but nothing is logged in event log.
- I've read lot of posts on the web bbut nothing helps me to fix.
- Dev and server has the same framework:

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I've tried to add a try-catch on program.cs, the start point of my project:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("CheckMail"))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("CheckMail", "Application");
                EventLog.WriteEntry("EventSystem", "EventSource created");
            }

            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new CheckMailSvc() };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
          string message = string.Format("Error starting Service {0}", ex.ToString());
          EventLog.WriteEntry("CheckMail", message, EventLogEntryType.Warning, 666);
        }
    }
}
```

nothing is trapped (neither rhe EventSource create event or an exception)

All other code is in try-catch, using log4net to log events (and in dev environment it works fine).

Comment: Have you attached a debugger and stepped into it?

Comment: no, I cant't mess with this production server, is not on my network and the process lasts too few seconds to do anything.
I've double checked alse that is not a framework misconfig, but dev pc and server has the same framework

 <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>

Comment: You say it's a production server - can you get the service to work locally or on a dev box?

Comment: yes, for sure, on my dev it works like a charm

Comment: You should get something in the System event log that the service started correctly.  If that happened then no exception occurred and there's something wrong with your logic (it succeeding but obviously not doing what you want).  If there was a failure in your service, you should see something in the Application event log under the ".NET Runtime" source.

Comment: Maybe your problem is not in the Main method. Try removing all the code from the OnStart method and install it that way. Maybe you get a timeout on connecting to the db or something like that on your OnStart method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions.
My OnStart is this:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            this.RequestAdditionalTime(30000);
            ServiceStart = DateTime.Now;
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["EventID"] = 666;
            log.Info("Service Started");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Service Configuration:");
            log.Info(sb.ToString());
            Timer t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SendMail));
            t.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(every));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.ErrorFormat("Error starting service: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

As you can see nothing strange happens, and I should see a starting message in Application log.

Comment: Few things, move the log.Info("Service started") to be the first line after try block and use System.Timers.Timer instead of System.Threading.Timer because from the documentation `"As long as you are using a System.Threading.Timer, you must keep a reference to it (on a class level). As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected."` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: Hi DZL.
I'm trying to build a WinForm App that does the same job, in order to figure out if the problem is the service or the logic.
I appreciate your suggestions, and I'll do as you say.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi,
Finally I've found the problem. there was an issue with the framework.
I've installed the .Net 4.5 and the service started fine.
Thanks to all that spent their time on my issue.

Have a nice day.